# Cannot access configuration page in drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am currently building a website using drupal 7.x. Unfortunately I cannot seem to enter the admin/config page. Every time I click on the configuration tab on the administration menu, I only get a blank page. Then I created another sample site. It also has the same problem and I am using WAMP server. I cleared cache and finds no difference. I have searched for similar issues, but could find none. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Increase the max_execution_time in php.ini file. It solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

A number of things can cause the White Screen of Death, but the most common things to check:

- As suggested above, memory limit may need to be increased.
- Have you enabled any modules other than those in Drupal core? Try disabling contributed modules and enable individually until you experience the error, to help you identify which module is causing trouble. If you can't access the modules admin page, you can disable them in the database - the system table has a 'status' field. 1 means enable, 0 is disabled.
- Could it be a permissions issue? Check admin access permissions or try logging in as the superuser (user ID 1).

Lots more and discussion [here](http://drupal.org/node/158043) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/482956).

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try...

Check your php error log for clues.
Create a simple file that calls phpinfo() and see what your memory_limit is.  It may need to be increased.
Try tweaking your php.ini to get it to display an error message instead of a blank page.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I increased the memory limit. But no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked this very issue to l10_update module, once I enable it, admin/config shows the WSOD. Once I disabled it, everything's fine. So:

```
- unchecking the localization_update module in the "modules" list
- de-installing it from the modules list
- deleting directory sites/all/modules/l10n_update
- and re-installing the module (from the same tar.gz file)
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1141160

Comment: This happed to you with Drupal 7.44? i just updated all core and modules and suddendly status report and admin/config pages start thowing 504 timeouts